# ElasticSearch: Migrate from 0.20.5 to 1.5.2 - single node - suggested steps?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have been sooooo happy with our ES rig, we haven't thought to upgrade it... but now we need to.

We run 0.20 on CentOs. Single, stand alone ES system.

We see the code related changes from 0.9 to 1.x, and those we have under control.

What are the best steps to get this rig current? (We could set up a 2nd server alongside, if that makes the process cleaner.)

Answer (score 0):

You're still running 0.20, wow!! If you're happy with the performance and capabilities of 0.20, you'll be uber-delighted with 1.5.2, for sure!

Before actually jumping into the upgrade, make sure to check the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-1.0.html) pages. A lot of things changed in the 1.0 version and you need to make sure that all your current assets (queries, client-side code, etc) are adapted first. Also note that starting with ES 1.2, dynamic scripting was [disabled by default](https://www.elastic.co/blog/scripting-security) so if you used dynamic scripts you'll need to take that into account and include `script.disable_dynamic: false` in your configuration, but 0.20 is so far away that you might not have to care about that.

Then, if you check the official [upgrade guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html), you'll see that jumping that many versions in one step, you'll need to go through a cluster restart, but since you have a single node it means your service will be unavailable during the upgrade. Note that bringing up a second node won't be possible because pre-1.0 and post-1.0 versions are not compatible.

Once you're ready, i.e. you've been through the breaking changes and adapted whatever you need to, make sure to [back up your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html#_0_90_x_and_earlier) just before diving into the upgrade.

Also make sure to upgrade your JDK to at least the latest Java 7, ideally Java 8 if that's possible, or ES 1.5.2 simply won't start.

Then you can shutdown your node with `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown'`, upgrade your ES installation to 1.5.2 and restart your node.

After the node has recovered and is fully started, you can [upgrade your indice files](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-upgrade.html) to the latest Lucene format using `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_upgrade'`.

Disclaimer: Note that there are so many things that changed between 0.2 and 1.5.2 that I might have missed some, but the points above should be enough to get you started. If you can train in a staging environment you might be able to figure it all out and and a smooth upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to create a new cluster from scratch and to re-index all the data.

The single and the most important argument in favor of this is that, since 1.3, [Elasticsearch has checksums added](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html). Meaning, things that move over the wire (network) are actually checked for correctness of transfer.

I am assuming "single, standalone" means one node. The checksum stuff doesn't make much sense for one node, but if you have more than one node there are chances something is corrupted.

Also, there are some settings that are saved together with the index itself (one thing that comes to mind is the precision step for range queries). To have a clean, updated index, I strongly recommend to re-index the data in the new 1.5 cluster.